# C# creating a ListBox application

Tags: c#

Im suppose to create a windows app in C# using a ListBox object. I need to create an order form with 6 different things to be purchased. Can someone please show me how to code for a list box?

Comment: its extra credit for my class

Comment: How about you give it a shot. get stuck somewhere and come back with a specific "how come this isn't working?" question.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps google for ["c# listbox tutorial"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=c%23+listbox+tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

you can use ListBox like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
   // Create an instance of the ListBox.
   ListBox listBox1 = new ListBox();
   // Set the size and location of the ListBox.
   listBox1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(200, 100);
   listBox1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10,10);
   // Add the ListBox to the form. 
   this.Controls.Add(listBox1);
   // Set the ListBox to display items in multiple columns.
   listBox1.MultiColumn = true;
   // Set the selection mode to multiple and extended.
   listBox1.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.MultiExtended;

   // Shutdown the painting of the ListBox as items are added.
   listBox1.BeginUpdate();
   // Loop through and add 50 items to the ListBox. 
   for (int x = 1; x <= 50; x++)
   {
      listBox1.Items.Add("Item " + x.ToString());
   }
   // Allow the ListBox to repaint and display the new items.
   listBox1.EndUpdate();

   // Select three items from the ListBox.
   listBox1.SetSelected(1, true);
   listBox1.SetSelected(3, true);
   listBox1.SetSelected(5, true);

   // Display the second selected item in the ListBox to the console.
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(listBox1.SelectedItems[1].ToString());
   // Display the index of the first selected item in the ListBox.
   System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(listBox1.SelectedIndices[0].ToString());             
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ListBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.aspx). This MSDN page has many examples. Take a look at the Items property which holds the list of items.